# Lazy loading with Staggered Grid View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

How can I implement lazy loading with Staggered Grid View in Flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view is not working well by list of images. GridView.builder is working well and GridView is loading more images when scroll reaches to bottom but unfortunately flutter_staggered_grid_view is not.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Are you using firebase? If so are you using paginate firestore?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40856) regarding built-in support for staggered view in Flutter. Unfortunately, there are numerous reports about performance to have very low especially when loading large list of images/contents. This could be the reason about the issue you are having.

There is also an alternative by using another package called [waterfall_flow](https://pub.dev/packages/waterfall_flow).

Although both have drawbacks as also mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40856#issuecomment-869122623).